# hi using NFS mount and sharing sever

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I'm trying to use NFS to A server and sharing B server Dir.

But now I have a problem with a message -> `mount.nfs: Connection timed out`

A server : 52.68.10.18 (example IP)

B server : 52.68.10.15

(A server )

```
vi /etc/exports
/home/files 52.68.10.15(rw,no_root_squash)

/etc/rc.d/init.d/nfs restart

/etc/rc.d/init.d/nfslock stop
```

(B server )

```
vi /etc/hosts

52.68.10.18 files.domain.com files

mkdir /home/files

mount -t nfs files.domain.com:/home/files /home/files

*chmod 777 setting
-A Server ntsysv run and nfs check +  nfslock check release.

/etc/rc.d/init.d/xinetd restart 

result : mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: This is a question about system administration, not programming; StackOverflow's scope is very explicitly limited to the latter. Consider ServerFault instead.

Comment: Also, don't **ever** use `chmod 777` (or any other umask with `o+w` unless against a directory with the `t` flag also set); it provides write access even to `nobody`, a user that's supposed to be completely harmless (and is used for code evaluating untrusted inputs in various network daemons).

Comment: (Also, there's a fair bit of troubleshooting not touched on here you'll want to cover in any repost of the question in an on-topic forum; for instance: Do you have any firewall rules in play that might block the relevant connections?)

Answer (score 0):

Check the services on the ports with nmap. It looks to me like you may be missing rpcbind.